# R: How to print names of calculated list element in a function?

Tags: r, function

I have two lists of more than 1500 elements, one vector list and one matrix list. Here some example data:

```
Z_matr <- list("111.2012"= matrix(c(0,0,100,200,0,0,0,0,50,350,0,50,50,200,200,0),
                             nrow = 4, ncol = 4, byrow = T),
           "112.2012"= matrix(c(10,90,0,30,10,90,0,10,200,50,10,350,150,100,200,10),
                              nrow = 4, ncol = 4, byrow = T))
p <- list("111.2012"=c(200, 1000, 100, 10), "112.2012"=c(300, 900, 50, 100))
```

On this two list I want to perform the following function, which of course works fine on this data:

```
kast <- function(Z_matr, p) {
  imp <- rowSums(Z_matr)
  exp <- colSums(Z_matr)
  x = p + imp
  ac = p + imp - exp  
  einsdurchx = 1/as.vector(x)    
  einsdurchx[is.infinite(einsdurchx)] <- 0
  A = Z_matr %*% diag(einsdurchx)
  return(A)
}

mapply(kast, Z_matr,p, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

However, I with my original lists I get an error. What I need is a counting of the list names that already had been calculated before it comes to the error list element (so that I know which of the list combinations creates an error). So, I tryed `print(names(A))` however I only get NULL, NULL... How can I get instead this, for this example 111.2012 and 112.2012 with print?

Comment: So that does not run, perhaps you meant to run it with an apply statement?

Comment: And if it is part of an apply statement, then the issue is probably that when you're inside a list element, the element (a la 'fight club') has no name. So something like this may allow you to do what you're after. But, not seeing the way your code actually runs, it's very difficult to say. `lapply(names(Z_matrix),function(name) {print(name);kast(Z_matrix[[name]],p[[name]])})`

Comment: Sorry, it was the wrong one. I updated code. I am using `mapply(...)` for this. And Z_matrix had the wrong name, changed into Z_matr. Sorry, forgot to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it up so you pass the names and use to index the object:

```
kast <- function(item, p) { print(item)
  imp <- rowSums(Z_matr[[item]])
  exp <- colSums(Z_matr[[item]])
  x = p + imp
  ac = p + imp - exp  
  einsdurchx = 1/as.vector(x)    
  einsdurchx[is.infinite(einsdurchx)] <- 0
  A = Z_matr[[item]] %*% diag(einsdurchx)
  return(A)
}

mapply(kast, names(Z_matr),p, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

The output... obviously you take out the print statement:

```
[1] "111.2012"
[1] "112.2012"
$`111.2012`
     [,1] [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,]  0.0 0.00 0.1818182 0.4347826
[2,]  0.0 0.00 0.0000000 0.0000000
[3,]  0.1 0.35 0.0000000 0.1086957
[4,]  0.1 0.20 0.3636364 0.0000000

$`112.2012`
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
[1,] 0.02325581 0.08910891 0.00000000 0.05357143
[2,] 0.02325581 0.08910891 0.00000000 0.01785714
[3,] 0.46511628 0.04950495 0.01515152 0.62500000
[4,] 0.34883721 0.09900990 0.30303030 0.01785714
```

This is a longstanding issue with the use of both `s/lapply` and `mapply`. Only the values and not the names of list items are passed to functions. They are only added back after the processing. You can see this if you attempt to `print(deparse(substitute(Z_matr)))` as the first call inside your example function.